# Boolean Truth Table C++

Tags: c++, truthtable

(p -> q) <-> [( r ^ t ) v (not) s]

This equation was given by my teacher for us to code a truth table for.  I already ran the checks for this by the teacher, but I'm having issues trying to populate the arrays:

```
bool p[32] = { false };
bool q[32] = { false }; 
bool r[32] = { false };
bool s[32] = { false };
bool t[32] = { false };
```

I know that I'm trying to allocate memory that wasn't set aside(getting "stack around variable 'p' was corrupted") by doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)           
    {
        toTrue[i] = true;
        for (int j = (counter * 2); j < (counter * 3); j++)     
        {
            toTrue[j] = true;
            for (int k = (counter * 4); k < (counter * 5); k++)     
            {
                toTrue[k] = true;
                for (int l = (counter * 6); l < (counter * 7); l++)     
                {
                    toTrue[l] = true;
                    for (int m = (counter * 8); m < (counter * 9); m++)     
                    {
                        toTrue[m];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is just based off the basic truth tables where a basic, 2 variable OR truth table would result:

```
a b    c
1 1    1
1 0    1
0 1    1
0 0    0
```

I'm not sure how to fix this issue without using vectors, which I have a very limited knowledge about, so not 100% confident going that route.  Another idea I had was to try and create multiple methods for populate p, then q, then r, etc.  But my teacher already told me previously that I was expanding the code more than I need to, and I feel like doing multiple methods like that would lead to him saying the same thing.  Any advice?

Comment: I have no idea what your loops are trying to do and the line `toTrue[m];` just adds to the confusion regarding the code's intention.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? It should help shed some light on the situation.

Comment: why not use an integer as a counter from 0 to 32 where each bit represent the truth value for p,q,r,s,t, get them by masking calculate and print.

Comment: @Cameron is correct 95% of more of the questions which I plan to ask here never get asked, because I debug them instead. Bailey, if you don't yet know the debugger, it is your best friend.

Comment: Your code will be much simpler, and clear, if all your five loops iterate from 0 to 1, each, and then inside the inner loop you combine all of these bits in one value Much clearer, much easier to understand, and fewer places for bugs to hide.

Answer (score 2):

A different and simple method.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

bool getBit(unsigned int uint, int position) { // !!! no range check  !!! 
     return (uint >> position) & 0x1;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[]) {

    bool p,q,r,s,t;
    
    cout << "p  q  r  s  t  (p -> q) <-> [( r ^ t ) v (not) s] \n";
    for ( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++ ) {
             
        cout << getBit(i,0) << "  ";
        cout << getBit(i,1) << "  ";
        cout << getBit(i,2) << "  ";
        cout << getBit(i,3) << "  ";
        cout << getBit(i,4) << "  ";
        
        cout  << ((!p || q)  == (( r ^ t ) ||  !s));
        
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```